# Link unlinked urls (BBCode) regex

Tags: php, regex

I need a regex that looks for any URL that isn't already inside [url(=...)]...[/url] tags. In other words, I want to link any URL that isn't linked and replace the link with [url]link[/url] so that the parser I'm using can take care of it as it usually would.

I've been trying to get an understanding of negative lookaheads (which is apparently what I should make use of), but I just can't get it down.

This is what I've got so far:

```
preg_replace('/(?!\[url(=.*?)?\])(https?|ftps?|irc):\/\/(www\.)?(\w+(:\w+)?@)?[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-])*.*(?!\[\/url\])/i',"[url]$0[/url]",$Str);
```

Thanks

Comment: You may also want to verify that the URL is not inside an `[img]` tag if your BBCode parser allows those.

Comment: Actually, I do not parse img tags at all on my site, so it's all good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solution:

```
<?php
$URLRegex = '/(?:(?<!(\[\/url\]|\[\/url=))(\s|^))';     // No [url]-tag in front and is start of string, or has whitespace in front
$URLRegex.= '(';                                        // Start capturing URL
$URLRegex.= '(https?|ftps?|ircs?):\/\/';                // Protocol
$URLRegex.= '\S+';                                      // Any non-space character
$URLRegex.= ')';                                        // Stop capturing URL
$URLRegex.= '(?:(?<![[:punct:]])|(?<=\/))(\s|\.?$)/i';  // Doesn't end with punctuation (excluding /) and is end of string (with a possible dot at the end), or has whitespace after

$Str = preg_replace($URLRegex,"$2[url]$3[/url]$5",$Str);
?>
```

Comment: Also allows a dot after the URL if it's at the end of the string (meaning, it will not be a part of the link).

Comment: Can you edit your answer to also match on urls that end in '/'? Not matching on urls that end in punctation is great, except that ending in '/' is almost always part of the url. I tried modifying `[:punct:]` using character class subtraction, but unfortunately that's not supported in PCRE.

Answer (score 1):

There's an excellent URL-matching regular expression here:

http://daringfireball.net/2009/11/liberal_regex_for_matching_urls

Comment: I tried the regex, but it catches [ and ] as well, so this doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Linkifying unlinked URLs is not trivial. There are a lot of gotchas (See: [The Problem with URLs](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/10/the-problem-with-urls.html)) and the thread of comments following this blog entry. The problem is compounded when you have URLs which are already linked that you wish to skip over. I have looked into this problem and have been working on a solution - an open source project: [LinkifyURL](https://github.com/jmrware/LinkifyURL). Here is the most recent incarnation of a function which does what you are asking. Note that the regex is NOT trivial (but neither is the problem as it turns out).

```php
function linkify($text) {
    $url_pattern = '/# Rev:20100913_0900 github.com\/jmrware\/LinkifyURL
    # Match http & ftp URL that is not already linkified.
      # Alternative 1: URL delimited by (parentheses).
      (\()                     # $1  "(" start delimiter.
      ((?:ht|f)tps?:\/\/[a-z0-9\-._~!$&\'()*+,;=:\/?#[\]@%]+)  # $2: URL.
      (\))                     # $3: ")" end delimiter.
    | # Alternative 2: URL delimited by [square brackets].
      (\[)                     # $4: "[" start delimiter.
      ((?:ht|f)tps?:\/\/[a-z0-9\-._~!$&\'()*+,;=:\/?#[\]@%]+)  # $5: URL.
      (\])                     # $6: "]" end delimiter.
    | # Alternative 3: URL delimited by {curly braces}.
      (\{)                     # $7: "{" start delimiter.
      ((?:ht|f)tps?:\/\/[a-z0-9\-._~!$&\'()*+,;=:\/?#[\]@%]+)  # $8: URL.
      (\})                     # $9: "}" end delimiter.
    | # Alternative 4: URL delimited by <angle brackets>.
      (<|&(?:lt|\#60|\#x3c);)  # $10: "<" start delimiter (or HTML entity).
      ((?:ht|f)tps?:\/\/[a-z0-9\-._~!$&\'()*+,;=:\/?#[\]@%]+)  # $11: URL.
      (>|&(?:gt|\#62|\#x3e);)  # $12: ">" end delimiter (or HTML entity).
    | # Alternative 5: URL not delimited by (), [], {} or <>.
      (                        # $13: Prefix proving URL not already linked.
        (?: ^                  # Can be a beginning of line or string, or
        | [^=\s\'"\]]          # a non-"=", non-quote, non-"]", followed by
        ) \s*[\'"]?            # optional whitespace and optional quote;
      | [^=\s]\s+              # or... a non-equals sign followed by whitespace.
      )                        # End $13. Non-prelinkified-proof prefix.
      ( \b                     # $14: Other non-delimited URL.
        (?:ht|f)tps?:\/\/      # Required literal http, https, ftp or ftps prefix.
        [a-z0-9\-._~!$\'()*+,;=:\/?#[\]@%]+ # All URI chars except "&" (normal*).
        (?:                    # Either on a "&" or at the end of URI.
          (?!                  # Allow a "&" char only if not start of an...
            &(?:gt|\#0*62|\#x0*3e);                  # HTML ">" entity, or
          | &(?:amp|apos|quot|\#0*3[49]|\#x0*2[27]); # a [&\'"] entity if
            [.!&\',:?;]?        # followed by optional punctuation then
            (?:[^a-z0-9\-._~!$&\'()*+,;=:\/?#[\]@%]|$)  # a non-URI char or EOS.
          ) &                  # If neg-assertion true, match "&" (special).
          [a-z0-9\-._~!$\'()*+,;=:\/?#[\]@%]* # More non-& URI chars (normal*).
        )*                     # Unroll-the-loop (special normal*)*.
        [a-z0-9\-_~$()*+=\/#[\]@%]  # Last char can\'t be [.!&\',;:?]
      )                        # End $14. Other non-delimited URL.
    /imx';
    $url_replace = '$1$4$7$10$13<a href="$2$5$8$11$14">$2$5$8$11$14</a>$3$6$9$12';
    return preg_replace($url_pattern, $url_replace, $text);
}
```

This solution does have some limitations, and recently I have been working on an improved version (which is simpler and works better) - but it is not yet ready for prime-time.

Be sure to take a look at the [linkify test page](http://jmrware.com/articles/2010/linkifyurl/linkify.html) where I have put together a list of really-hard-to-match-in-the-wild URLs.

Comment: Curious if you ever got your improved version working?

Comment: @Jeff Widman - Sorry, but I never finished the newer version - this one here is still the best one I've got for the moment.